# Get name of a Zend_Form_Element in FormErrors Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, view-helpers

I have a `MyNameSpace_View_Helper_FormErrors` Class which extends the standard FormErrors Class and sets the HTML for the ErrorMessage itself.

I have to give the errormessage container an id based on the name of the element for which the error is thrown.

```
<ul id='errormsg_$ELEMENTNAME'>
```

It seems the `View_Helper_FormErrors` has no "link" to the Element, so is there any way to get the name or object of the Element which throws the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will also have to overwrite Zend_Form_Decorator_Error to give the Element to the View Helper.

see Zend_Form_Decorator_Error line 60:

```
$errors    = $view->formErrors($errors, $this->getOptions());
```

will change to:

```
$errors    = $view->formErrors($errors, $this->getOptions(), $this->getElement());
```

Tanks to @venimus , without his answer i wouldnt have looked in the decorator :-)

Answer (score 1):

you are probably speaking about the Errors *decorator*. However there is additional FormErrors decorator that renders all the errors of the form (not single element)

In *element decorators* you can access the element by `$this->getElement()`

in the element ViewScripts you can access the element by `<? $this->element ?>`

Comment: the Errors Decorator is renderd via Zend_View_Helper_FormErrors. but nevermind, you lead me to a way to solve this. see my answer below.